# jQuery - Running a Function When Class Names Are Added And/Or Removed

Tags: jquery, css, function, event-handling

I'm developing a function with a conditional statement that (for now) has to run an alert when a class name is removed from a div layer. Here's the code:

```
<div class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">panel</div>
<div><a href="#" class="control">control</a></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.control').hover(
        function() {
            $('.ui-tabs-panel').removeClass('ui-tabs-hide');
        },
        function() {
            $('.ui-tabs-panel').addClass('ui-tabs-hide');
        }
    );
    if ($('.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)')) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
//-->
</script>
```

The whole "control" link, and the function connected to it, are just there to trigger the adding and removal of the class name.

Right now, the alert comes up when the page is loaded, and it shouldn't, so I think I must be getting the syntax wrong there. Removing the ui-tabs-hide class from the div with the "control" link does not trigger the alert, and it should. I'm guessing there's some kind of event binder I need to incorporate, but I don't know event binders very well.

Can anyone help me out with this, please?

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't call the function at the same time you remove the class? That'd be ideal. Barring that, random thought that may or may not work: when removing the class, update a hidden input field, then attach an onchange listener to the input field.

Comment: It would be ideal, but what I was trying to say was the "control" link isn't going to be there in the final solution. I'm trying to write something that will interact with another plugin that adds/removes the class. The "control" link is only there to simulate that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can detect an "event" such as a class name manipulation on an element.

The reason you're seeing the alert on page load is that it's in an `if` block contained within jQuery's `$(document).ready` function, which fires once on page load. In essence, you haven't attached this to any event other than the DOM ready event. Therefore, it fires when the page loads and DOM is ready, and the `if` statement evaluates to true.

You also need to use the `.length` property in your expression:

```
if ($('.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)').length) {
    alert('hello');
}

// Or...
if ($('.ui-tabs-panel').not('.ui-tabs-hide').length) {
    alert('hello');
}
```

**NOTE**

I'd just like to caution here that the above code will depend on what you are attempting to do with your class change detection activities - `.length` will give you the total number of matching elements, so if you have more than one `.ui-tabs-panel`'s, this could give you a false positive. You would need to consider something like an `.each()` call on the jQuery result if you want to do something with the results, or some other thing, in the event of more than one result.

A way could be to run a timeout and attempt to check if the `ui-tabs-panel` class elements also have the `ui-tabs-hide` class:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/4cF5v/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.control').hover(
        function() {
            $('.ui-tabs-panel').removeClass('ui-tabs-hide');
        },
        function() {
            $('.ui-tabs-panel').addClass('ui-tabs-hide');
        }
    );
    runCheck();
});

function runCheck(){
    if ($('.ui-tabs-panel').hasClass('ui-tabs-hide')) {
        alert('hello');
    }
    setTimeout(function(){runCheck()},5000);
}
```

I created a `runCheck()` function, put the `.hasClass()` call in it, and then create a timeout, which will run `runCheck()` again, set the timeout again, and keep going.

I set the timeout to be 5000 so that your browser wouldn't enter an infinite loop (it checks about every 5 seconds). In practice it should probably be tuned in somewhere between 50 and 500; 1000 is equal to 1000 milliseconds, or 1 second.

Here it is with a 50 millisecond timeout and another method that won't lock your computer into an `alert()` loop:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/k44qR/

Mouseover the control link, mouseout, then mouseover again, and you'll see it start, stop, then start again.

Comment: I really have to detect when the class is removed in an independent function. I can't add a function trigger to the "control" link.

Comment: Tom, I'm not following your comment. runCheck() is an independent function, and I'm not sure what you mean in the second part of your question.

Comment: The bit with control only has to do with the code you posted; the actual runCheck() runs entirely separately from the .hover() call on the hover class elements. Follow my second link and let me know if that is what you are needing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom event

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/k44qR/2/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.control').hover(
        function() {
            $('.ui-tabs-panel').removeClass('ui-tabs-hide').trigger("displayPanel");
        },
        function() {
            $('.ui-tabs-panel').addClass('ui-tabs-hide');
        }
    );

    $('.ui-tabs-panel').bind("displayPanel",function(){alert("hello")});

});
```

Comment: I really have to detect when the class is removed in an independent function. I can't add a function trigger to the "control" link.